# dropzone.js: How can I rename file?

Tags: javascript, php, rename, dropzone.js

I want to rename a file uploaded with dropzone.js. I have read the other question of rename file with dropzone, but I don't understand.

I've tried this:

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) { 
    var abdocument.getElementById("a").value
    var nick = document.getElementById("b").value;
    formData.append("fileName", a+ " - " + b);
    });
  }
};
```

but then how can I use this "fileName"? I've to use in php function? This is mine:

```
<?php

$upload_folder = 'uploads';
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $temp_file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $target_path = dirname( __FILE__ ) .  '/' . $upload_folder . '/';
  $target_file =  $target_path . $_FILES['file']['name'];


  if( file_exists( $target_path ) ) {
    move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_file);
  } else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
  }
}

?>
```

or can I rename via javascript?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have to do this:

`$_FILES['file']['name']  = ($_POST["fileName"]);`

Answer (score 0):

simply set it at $_FILE superglobal as follow:

```
 $_FILES['file']['name']="your_new_file_name";
```

Comment: Ok, but how I can get my "new file name" from formData.append("fileName", a+ " - " + b);? a and b are input text on html page.